# R as.numeric use when ranking data error messade NA coercion

Tags: r

There is some feature of AS.NUMERIC that does not function as expected. I receive NAs introduced by coercion. perhaps there is another function I should use. Or use as.numeric in a different way.

it only goes wrong when the function leads to only one result. When ranked it works fine. Without as.numeric the ranking does not function properly as then it ranks based on 1 as forexample 1, 1002,2,233,25 ..... which should have been 1,2,25,233,1002. It is a bit of a circle.

let me know how could it be improved.

best("MD","heart attack")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In best("MD", "heart attack") : NAs introduced by coercion
best("MD","pneumonia")
 "GREATER BALTIMORE MEDICAL CENTER"

See the function and the output below:

```
best<- function(state, outcome){
  stateCorrect <- c("AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","DC","FL","GA","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VI","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY","GU")
  outcomeCorrect <-c("heart attack","heart failure","pneumonia")
  if(!(state %in% stateCorrect)){
    stop('invalid state')
    }
  else if(!(outcome %in% outcomeCorrect)){
    stop('invalid outcome')
    }

  thedata<-read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  mylist <- split(thedata, thedata$State)
  tx<-mylist[[state]]
  if(outcome=="heart attack"){
    k<-tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack"]]
    l<-k[!is.na(k)]
    xtx<- min(as.numeric(l))
    ytx<-which(tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack"]] == xtx)
    z<-tx[["Hospital.Name"]][ytx]
  }
  if(outcome=="heart failure"){
    k<-tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"]]
    l<-k[!is.na(k)]
    xtx<- min(as.numeric(l))
    ytx<-which(tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"]] == xtx)
    z<-tx[["Hospital.Name"]][ytx]
  }
  if(outcome=="pneumonia"){
    k<-tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia"]]
    l<-k[!is.na(k)]
    xtx<- min(as.numeric(l))
    ytx<-which(tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia"]] == xtx)
    z<-tx[["Hospital.Name"]][ytx]
  }
  rankdata<-z[order(z)]
  rankdata[1]
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you try to apply `as.numeric` to a `factor`? In that case try `as.numeric(as.character(x))`

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by `It is a bit of a circle.` part ?

Comment: @count, `colClasses = "character"` in `read.csv`, so no need for `as.character` in ur query

Comment: @parth True. Some sample data would be good though.

Comment: @count  I found the issue with the code. I am looking for the minimum in tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"]], which has not yet been converted to numeric. I have corrected my code to k<-tx[["Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack"]]
    m<-as.numeric(k)
    xtx<- min(m,na.rm=TRUE)
    ytx<-which(m == xtx)
    z<-tx[["Hospital.Name"]][ytx] it works now. Only I still receive warning message next to the correct result

Comment: @ parth Thanks! i solved it see above